# Play Two Audio Waveforms Simultaneously, One Per Stereo Channel LabVIEW

Tags: audio, labview, audio-channels

I have two sine waves I built in LabVIEW, and I need to take these two separate waves and play them at the same time, one in my left stereo speaker and the other in my right. My channels are built, but I cannot figure out how to not play the wave in both speakers, so it just sounds like they are both playing in both speakers. They are formatted as waveform outputs, and I think I might need to mess with array indexes but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you show what you have done, that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to send an array of waveforms to the Sound Output Write.vi; iirc, the 0 index will be left and the 1 index will be right.